# Разобрать слайс на аргументы

Tags: golang, slice

Всем привет.

```
func FindingUname(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) []UsernamesFromDB {
    name := GetUName(w, r)
    command := "select token from AuthData where username=$1"
    db, _ := sql.Open("postgres", dbconnect)
    rowsUname, _ := db.Query(command, name)
    db.Close()
    var Na []UsernamesFromDB
    for rowsUname.Next() {
        n := UsernamesFromDB{}
        rowsUname.Scan(&n.UserNamevariable)
        Na = append(Na, n)
    }
    rowsUname.Close()
    return Na
}
```

Данная функция возвращает слайс. В слайсе несколько значений. Мне нужно эти значения сверить с определенной строкой. Как мне разобрать вернувшийся слайс и вытащить только все значения и проверить с заданной строкой по очереди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

через цикл прогнал слайс и получил отдельные значения. Вопрос закрыт)))

```
func Get(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    data:=FindingUname(w,r)
    for i=0; i<len(data);i++{
        fmt.Println(data[i])
    }
}
```